# referencing a dataframe variable as an argument in a function in R

Tags: r, function, arguments, datasetvalue

I am attempting to develop a function to edit outliers in a dataset variable (data_oc$PP_E2_A_OV). To do so, I use the function below. However, the function does not reference the dataset variable as the argument, but seemingly just the string of characters("new_variable"). I tried to use ensym() to encode new_variable before it is referenced, but this didn't  work either. Without using ensym, the function creates a new variable in data_oc called "new_variable," as opposed to referencing the actual variable in data_oc. My question is, how do I get the commands in the function (i.e within) to reference the dataset variable (data_oc$PP_E2_A_OV), which is stored as a column of numeric values in data_oc?

```
library("Routliers")
library("stats")

data_oc<-data

new.function<- function(new_variable) {
  {
    new_variable<-ensym(new_variable)
  }
  b <- outliers_mad(new_variable, b=1.4826, na.rm=TRUE) 
  print(b)
  {
    #store UL + LL
    UL<-b$UL_CI_MAD 
  }
  {
    LL<-b$LL_CI_MAD
  }
  #create variable slightly less than UL for replacement
  {
    UL_l <-UL - .1
  }
  #create variable slightly greater than LL for replacement
  {
    LL_g <-LL + .1
  }
  {
    data_oc <- within(data_oc,new_variable[new_variable>=UL] <- UL_l)
  }
  {
    data_oc <- within(data_oc,new_variable[new_variable<=LL] <- LL_g)
  }
  {
    #CHECK
    print(outliers_mad(new_variable, b=1.4826, na.rm = TRUE))
  }
  # output new outlier corrected data
  {
    data_oc <<- data_oc
  }
}

new.function("data_oc$PP_E2_A_OV")
```

Comment: `new.function<- function(data, new_variable)` and in the function's body, `new_variable<- data[[new_variable]]`.

Comment: Hi Rui, thank you so much! When I attempted your suggestion, I ran into the error "Error in data_oc[[new_variable]] : subscript out of bounds."

Comment: Call as `new.function(data_oc, "PP_E2_A_OV")`.